# determinant of block "matrix" where the blocks are tensors of different rank

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, tensors, positive-definite, block-matrices

I want to compute the determinant of the Hessian

$$ \boldsymbol H = \begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol A & \boldsymbol B & \boldsymbol C \\
\boldsymbol D & \boldsymbol E & \boldsymbol F \\
\boldsymbol G & \boldsymbol H & I 
\end{bmatrix} $$

to check for positive definiteness.

Here, $\boldsymbol A, \boldsymbol B, \boldsymbol D, \boldsymbol E$ are fourth order tensors in a three-dimensional space, whose coefficients can be written as a $9\times9$ matrix.
$\boldsymbol C, \boldsymbol F, \boldsymbol G, \boldsymbol H$ are second order tensors, whose coefficients can be written as a $1\times9$ matrix. $I$ is a scalar. All coefficients are real numbers. That said, $\boldsymbol H$ represents a $19\times19$ matrix. How can I exploit the block structure to compute the determinant? Are there special treatments if the blocks are rank2 / rank4 tensors?

Comment: I know. Usually I think of the coefficients of a rank2 tensor as a 3x3 matrix. Similarly a 3x3x3x3 matrix as for a rank4 tensor. But thinking like this, I do not come up with a square matrix and can not compute a determinant